# Keep text in a div on a single line when absolutely positioned inside a parent div smaller than the text div?

Tags: html, css

I need the text to continue on a single line automatically pushing the #chi div to the length of the text, extending past the boundaries of the #par div.

See the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MEBtu/

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#chi{white-space: nowrap}
```

Comment: ha ha epic!, should have asked this before the 10hours of work I tried to get around this ha ha. Thank you! :D